# Am i missing something in this code?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to install google tag manager with provided code by google tag manager site. But it return error after i implement it in the first .

This is the code :

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-K6457M"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

The error return is "Unexpected start tag token (iframe) in the frameset phase" and "Unexpected end tag (noscript)"

Any idea guys?

Comment: Use it before body tag closing..

Comment: Nothing in your question is about php.

Comment: @Frayne your info is not correct! Check out the GTM tag implementation documentation. The code MUST be immediately after the opening <body> tag, not before.

Answer (score 0):

How is your page file saved in your editor? ASCII, UTF-8, anything else?
When you change the file encoding, does the error go away?

Another helpful info might be reading the official quick start guide by Google https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart

Something else that I though of, is your tag manager code within an open PHP code tag? If yes, is it properly called within your code?

Something like...

```
<?php
.....php code here

<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-K6457M"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>    </noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Can you post your full code?

The information that @Frayne Konok gave you is not correct! The code must be right after the opening  tag, NOT before the closing tag!

Comment: I am not saying to put it before opening tag, take a deep look at my comment.

Comment: As i said is just put the script before body tag closing like: `<body> Conetnt goes here ...... Now put the script of tag manager</body>`

Comment: @Frayne Right before body tag closing is incorrect, it MUST be right after the opening tag! I meant the closing tag not the opening, it's still incorrect. Updated my answer.